# Automatic test for Excel export

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

I have a simple method, which takes an IEnumerable of an object and export that as an Excel workbook. The object could be something like a student (to use the classic example).

```
public class Student 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
}
```

And then the method I need to test

```
public void ExportStudents(IEnumerable<Student> students)
{
    // This method will save the students to an Excel workbook with a known name
    ...
}
```

I would like some sort of test of this, but the best I can come up with is a console application that you can run manually, something like this:

```
public void Main() 
{
    var students = new List<Student>
    {
        { Name = "John Doe", Age = 19, StudentId = 1 }, 
        { Name = "Max Power", Age = 21, StudentId = 2 },
        ...etc
    }

    // Export the list as a workbook
    WorkbookExporter.ExportStudents(students);
}
```

And then inspect the workbook manually. But this seems like a very slow and primitve way of testing. How do you test something like this - or to take another example, something sending an e-mail - in a smarter way?

Comment: In your case you could create method which will read data from excel file, so then you could write data by your method-under-the-test, and then read data back and compare using another method. Which, in its turn, would be nice to test using some excel file with known data. For unit test, I believe, you know that xUnit or NUnit could be used - actually you could implement any type of the algorithms there. When it comes to e-mails sending, I know that for web applications special frameworks could be used - but again, those are integration tests or even system-level tests.

Comment: @kosist would you see this as a unit test? I am thinking that 1) It is too slow to run. 2) It has external dependencies (Excel)

Comment: So that's why I consider it rather as integration test. But nothing stops us from using unit test framework for this - because all we need is to automate test, and use assertion to check the outputs.

Comment: @kosist so something like making a seperate project (in addition to the one for unit testing) with NUnit and use that one for higher level tests?

Comment: I guess yes. Then this project will have dependencies to other external modules, and another unit test project will not have redundant dependencies.